# Count results based on a multiple VLOOKUPs?

Tags: excel

I wan't really sure how to title this one, but I'll try and explain this the best I can.

I've got a workbook and on my Dashboard I have a table that lists the stats I want to provide.  It's all about helpdesk tickets, so I want to know how many tickets each group has raised.  In my data though, each ticket is listed by the persons name, not group.

What I have done is created a table in my 'Data' sheet where the name is next to the group.  For example:

```
| A1               | A2          |
|:-----------------|------------:|
| John Smith       |    Helpdesk |         
| Ben Jones        |    Helpdesk |       
| Will Smith       |  Management |
```

What I want to do is say:

On my 'Tickets' sheet, give me the total number of rows where the name is equal to that of the group I want to check.

The results would be something like:

```
| Group            | Tickets     |
|:-----------------|------------:|
| Helpdesk         |            5|         
| Management       |            2|
```

Im a little unsure on where to even start with this one

Comment: Create a table that lists each persons name and their group. Then add another column to your dashboard table using a `VLOOKUP()`. Then create a pivot table.

Answer (score 0):

*so I want to know how many tickets each group has raised.*

Do you need the total Count of tickets raised by group?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula to calculate the number of tickets per department, in the second column of the resulttable (starting at B2 and copy down). In the first column are the department names, starting at A2.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(LOOKUP(Tickets!A1:A100,UserDeparment!A1:B20)=Results!A2))
```

Tickets!A1:A100 are the users for every ticket (ticketData). UserDeparment!A1:B20 holds the department (Column B) for each User (Column A).